# Maintaining result of API call to use throughout web application C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application using C# ASP.NET MVC5 and I have a call to an API that takes in co ordinate values and returns a physical address (Reverse geocoding similar to googles geocoding API). Since I can only make a limited number of calls a day I want to limit them by storing the result of them somewhere, rather than just destroying the result of them at the end of a method. I want to perform tasks with the API result on order objects, such as printing reports, labels, pickslips etc, but each time I perform these tasks it makes another API call.

Is there some way I can store this result somewhere within the .NET environment so I can use it as frequently as I like without using a data store like saving/retrieving the result from the database?

Any help with this would be great,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML5 Local Storage. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

or you can use session variable
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx